# Scala :How to differentiate list from other data types when using Any

Tags: scala

I have a function which takes the parameter. Its data type is `Any`. I want to differentiate `List` from other data types like `String`, `Int`, `Double`. I want to check if the parameter value is list or not here is my code

```
val userList: List[String] = List("1","2")
val user = "UserList"
val name = "Name"

myFunction(user, userList)

def myFunction(fieldName: String, value: Any): Unit = {
  if (fieldName.equals(user)) {
    value match {
      case list: List[String] => print("its a list perform operation accordingly")
    }
  }
  else {
    log.info("its a string")
  }
}
```

But the compiler generates the warning:

> non-variable type argument String in type pattern List[String] (the
>   underlying of List[String]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by
>   erasure

I want to fix this warning message.

I do not want to use `asInstanceOf` like

```
val list = value.asInstanceOf[List[String]]
```

to avoid this warning message.

Comment: You cannot check against erased types at runtime. The best way around this is to have compile-time typesafety. That means not having this `Any` in the first place. Or maybe you don't need to care about the component type and just check for `: List[_]`

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't care about the element type of the `List` you can just leave the type blank:

```
case _: List[_] => print("its a list perform operation accordingly")
```

You cannot test specifically for `List[String]` because this information is not available when the test is executed. It you want to do this you will need to use a type class or polymorphism.

Comment: this will end up with the same warning message

Comment: @swaheed Which version of Scala are you using? There is no warning in `2.12.8`

Comment: Scala code runner version 2.12.8 -- Copyright 2002-2018, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

Comment: also i want List[String] and you are giving me List[_] how will i match it with List[String]

Comment: As I said in the answer, you can't match on `List[String]`. It is hard to give a solution without knowing why you need an `Any` value in the first place and how you intend to process it.

Comment: i want the one same function to deal with any input that's why i used Any

Comment: "i want the one same function to deal with any input that's why i used Any" Why exactly do you want that? That is undercutting the compile-time type system. And with erased types, you cannot use the run-time type system.

Comment: so i should separate the function one for string and one for list ? would that be the right approach ?

Comment: @swaheed If that is an option then, yes, have a polymorphic function with a version for each type. But at some point you may want to look at typeclasses which are the most powerful way of dealing with this.